# How to make an svg masked image compatible with Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

Lately i have created an svg masked image that works perfectly in Chrome but done not work in My version of Internet explorer. Here is the End result expected from my svg

[image: End Result Expected]

This is my svg code

```
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M10,70 Q0,80 10,90 L70,150 Q80,160 90,150 L150,90 Q160,80 150,70 L90,10 Q80,0 70,10z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' />
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' />
```

And this is my css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.photo_rectangle_inverse {
  height: 160px;
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)
}
```

Since the svg was not working in Internet Explorer (IE 11), after reading [this article](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) that talks about compatibility issue with Browsers, I added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

To the top of my page because IE Edge based on the article seems to be the most compatible with Svg.

But still the svg shape is not displaying.

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/omat2km1/) . Note Jsfiddle does not allow meta tag

**How to make an svg masked image compatible with Internet Explorer  ?**

Tks

Comment: How please ? Can you be more specific please or give me an example based on what i have written already ? Tks

Comment: Thanks it is working . However it does not display the left corner of the shape. It cuts it . Can you please help me solve it ? And you can add this as an answer so that i May validate it.  Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/omat2km1/3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE won't apply an SVG clip to a html element, so you need an SVG `<image>` element rather than an HTML `<img>` element e.g.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo_rectangle_inverse {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)
}
```

```html
    <svg height="100%" width="100%" >
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape">
          <path d="M10,70 Q0,80 10,90 L70,150 Q80,160 90,150 L150,90 Q160,80 150,70 L90,10 Q80,0 70,10z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>

      <image height="160px" width="170px" xlink:href='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' class='photo_rectangle_inverse'/>
      <image transform="translate(170,0)" height="160px" width="170px" xlink:href='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' />
    </svg>'
```

[image: IE 11 screenshot]

Comment: Thanks but please how to display two images on the same line like i did in the question. The answer you gave me displays only one image. Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/omat2km1/5/

Comment: Yes sir but it was part of my question . Can you please help me out with that ? Thanks

Comment: I already did. Press Run code snippet in the answer. There's two images.

Comment: Please sir when i run the code snippet it displays only one image on a line.  Screenshoot http://i.imgur.com/xiejUQg.png

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my answer. This is what I see when I press Run code snippet. I've no idea how you're getting one image.

Comment: Strange, I get only one image on chrome but the two in mozilla. Tks anyway sir

Comment: there is a semi colon that it shouldn't be <image height="160px" width="170px" xlink:href='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg'(;) class='photo_rectangle_inverse'/>