# "webkit-background-clip: text" equivalent in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, webkit, gradient

I want to place a text with gradient color for example:
https://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/yoksel/CCaiPDe6/embed/result,html,css/html,css,result#

It is very easy using `-webkit-background-clip: text` in `CSS`. Unfortunately, it is not supported in IE 11.

Is there any way to achieve the goal?

Thanks in advance.

Update: Mistakenly, I initially mentioned IE 10. But IE 11 is where I have problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Use svg mask. It works from ie9+ https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/

Comment: working in IE11, same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181591/how-to-make-an-svg-masked-image-compatible-with-internet-explorer